# What is a matrix variable in semidefinite programming?

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I am reading papers on semidefinite programming, and in several places I encountered matrix variables. What does it exactly mean? Does it effectively mean $n \times n$ scalar variables?

Comment: If the matrix is symmetric, you don't need $n^2$ scalar variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In semidefinite programming, the constraints on the matrix variable commonly include the constraint that $X$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite.  It's certainly true that such a matrix variable can be stored as a vector of $n^{2}$ numbers, but there's no simple way to express the semidefiniteness constraint without referring to $X$ as a matrix.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please detail a bit more on what it means to "express the semidefiniteness constraint"? Does it mean simply writing $M \succeq 0$ or it's something more than that?

Comment: The problem is that there is no simple way to write the constraint $M \succeq 0$ in terms of the elements of the matrix $M$.

Comment: OK, after playing a bit with yalmip, I now understand that a matrix variable "consists" of quadratically many scalar variables and allows for a convenient way to impose semidefiniteness constraints. One can also impose usual linear or quadratic constraints on various slices/entries of the matrix variable. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  It's common to write a linear constraint $\sum \sum_{i,j} A_{i,j}X_{i,j}=b$ as $\mbox{tr}(A^{T}X)=b$.